# Xpage Component using UIDialog, UIDialog does not render its children

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to develope a component for my company wich should have an integrated dialog. Creating the component was easy until i hit the point with the Dialog. I want to use the `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dialog.UIDialog` for my component because it has some nice features wich i want to use so creating my own dialog with a ClientSideDojo is not an option.

Normaly when adding a component to another i use `component.getChildren().add(MyNewComp),`but when i try this Code:

```
public class myComponentWithADialog extends UIComponentBase implements FacesComponent {
    //...other Code...
    public void buildContents(FacesContext context, FacesComponentBuilder builder)
                throws FacesException {

          UIDialog dialog = new UIDialog();
            TypedUtil.getChildren(container).add(dialog);
            dialog.setStyleClass("dlgUserPref");
            dialog.setTitle("titelxyz");
            dialog.setId("TagDialog"); 

            UIPanelEx panel = new UIPanelEx();
            panel.setTagName("div");
            panel.setStyle("border:2px solid red;");
            panel.setStyleClass("lotusList lotusTags lotusRelatedTags");

            dialog.getChildren().add(panel);
            this.getChildren.add(dialog);
    }
  //....
}
```

My Panel does not display inside the dialog when calling `XSP.openDialog('dialogClientId')` in my browser the dialog is shown but empty.

I already tried several other methods like `dialog.getPopupContent.getChildren().add()` but then i get the error: `javax.faces.component.UIPanel incompatible with com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dialog.UIDialog$PopupContent`.

Also i tried to find a solution on google but i only found a entry at [openNTF](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/discussion.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=BDDAA01752905B3486257A6400391A71) from someone with the same problem but also without any solution.

**Note:** I also tried to 'inject' some content to a standard `<xe:dialog>` and to a `<px:panel>` inside the `<xe:dialog>` via a button with SSJS like [keithstric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509934/keithstric) does in his [blog](http://www.keithstric.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/dx/KSTD-8MGJTA). Code:

```
var dialog:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dialog.UIDialog = 
   getComponent('extlibdialog');

    if(dialog.getChildren().size() > 0) {     
        dialog.getChildren().clear(); 
    } 

    var TextField:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspOutputText = new com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspOutputText();
        TextField.setTitle("test");
        TextField.setId("testTextField");
        TextField.setValue("<p>This is the new Content</p>");

    dialog.getChildren().add(TextField);
```

This code works fine for a standard `<xp:panel>` outside a dialog but not on the dialog itself or a panel inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The dialogue is not pre - rendered when the page is loaded, but when you actually call for it in XSP.openDialog(...)

So you need to get your code run in that event (mobile now, can't check if it is exposed).

Plan B: do use a Dojo dialogue that is backed by a rest control, so you can transport whatever data you need back and forth.

A word of caution: popup dialogs are a UI concept transplanted from desktop apps. They are alien to Web apps and mostly not working in mobile. Consider and Inline form instead (or a wizard)

Comment: But if i create a custom component where i add a UIDialog Component, and then add some Children to it why arent they rendered when the XSP.openDialog() on the client is called? Where do i have to add all components i want to display in the dialog, if they are no Children. I could run the SSJS when the dialog is displayed then i maby get everything i need inside the dialog but that does not help me with my component.

Comment: You define the children static in the source of the XPage.

Comment: And what to do in my Component? Declaring them static and/or final doesn't help.

Comment: Not CODE. Markup. Why are you trying to manually create children? I'm not clear about that. Just compose them as regular XPages controls at design time.

Comment: This component will become part of our company ControlLibrary and should be integrated in all our applications. So until someone invents something to share CustomControls over the UpdateSite i have to create the components in (java/jsf) and share them as Library. The part with the SSJS in my question is just a note that i have tried some different ways to inject the something inside the dialog control without any success

Comment: Did you try to put a Editable Area into the dialog? The mechanism is possible by taking a hint from this: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-99W7MJ (instead of another NSF, add it to a lib -> or write them in Java)

Comment: I still don't understand the need to inject anything into a dialog at runtime